# How can I view the active threads of a running program?

Tags: windows, troubleshooting

I know I can see all running **processes** in Task Manager. But how can I see the single threads that run *inside* these processes?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

1. Get [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).
2. Enable **Show Details for All Processes** from the **File** menu:

   [image]
3. In the main pane, select the process you're interested in:

   [image]
4. Open the context menu (right-click) for the selected process and click **Properties**:

   [image]
5. On the **Threads** tab, you'll be able to see a list of the running threads inside that process:

   [image]

### Symbols

If your troubleshooting requires you to get more detail, it is often very helpful to load debugging *symbols* into Process Explorer. This is how:

1. If you don't already have a Windows debugger installed, you're going to have to install the [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx) first.
2. In Process Explorer, open **Configure Symbols...** from the **Options** menu:

   [image]
3. If you have the Debugging Tools (or another Windows debugger) installed, Process Explorer will automatically find the `dbghelp.dll` file. Otherwise, set the correct path here.

   [image]

   The **Symbols path** should look something like:

   ```
   SRV*C:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
   ```

   The only part you'll want to adjust is `C:\Symbols`. That's the location where the debugging symbols will be cached.

Comment: Omg, why didn't they built it in task manager, it is an obvious feature…

Comment: ...obvious feature for devs: Windows is for grandma-level users so it is better kept hidden.