# 'System and compressed memory' CPU spiking and causing lag Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, performance, dell-inspiron, high-cpu-usage

After a random amount of time after reboot (20 minutes to 2 hours), my laptop would have considerable lag, locking up for 2-3 seconds every 6-10 seconds.  I tried to follow [What is the cause of a high CPU usage of 'system and compressed memory' in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1020629/what-is-the-cause-of-a-high-cpu-usage-of-system-and-compressed-memory-in-windo) because the symptoms were similar, but the root cause was different.

Observing Task Manager during these lockups, 'System and compressed memory' would be the only thing spiking and would reach about 25% before returning to a negligible level.  Following what magicandre1981 did in the other thread, I used WPRUI to capture the activity and opened it in WPA.  I drilled down the CPU spikes through ntoskrnl.exe -> ndis.sys -> rt640x64.sys.  Looking up that driver, it was for the onboard NIC (Realtek).

Updating to the latest drivers from Dell didn't help.  Since it's a laptop and I'm not likely to use the wired NIC anytime, I just disabled it in Device Manager, and the problem stopped immediately.

I thought I'd type this up since I spent so much time researching the problem.  Big thanks to @magicandre1981 for his work in the other question and for leading me towards WPRUI and WPA.

[image: WPA Sreenshot]

Comment: @hennes curious, why did you remove the realtek tag? the culprit was realtek drivers.

Comment: Seemed to match the idea of these.  
http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8402/manufacturer-company-tags-are-back-again
  Not really sure why it is not on that list. Now [realtek-network] or [realtek-audio] I could understand, but [realtek] (the firm) seems just as broad as those deprecated tags.

Comment: That makes sense.  If I had privs to add a proper tag I would

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to the latest device drivers is the first step.  If that doesn't work, disable the onboard wired NIC (Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller) in Device Manager, and the problem should stop immediately.

Comment: It is an answer...

Comment: This was the answer to the question.

Comment: @JonnyBlaze If this answers your question, mark it as the accepted answer. (Although the first sentence should be moved to your question.) If this is not an answer, but instead an extension to your question, update your question with this information and delete this answer.

Comment: @Ouroborus I can't for 2 days, I tried.  The first sentence is in the question already.  Plus the first sentence is information that may be able to help someone else, and it's the first thing they should try.

Comment: What confused me, is the first sentence, it has no business being in the answer.

Comment: @Ramhound I clarified it a bit, but I do feel that updating the drivers should be the first step and therefore should remain in the answer, unless you can point me to a community guide that states otherwise.

Comment: try the latest driver from Realtek and not Dell: http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false

Comment: have you tried the latest drivers from Realtek and not Dell? do they fix it?