# Using WPA to diagnose high CPU usage of "system and compressed memory" in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cpu, analysis, high-cpu-usage

Because the computer (ACER Aspire V5-122P) was running slow and was quite messy, I  reinstalled Windows 10 and installed all the updates recommended. I also installed Avast and MalwareBytes.

It is still running slow and I can see it is because of the infamous 'system and compressed memory'. As suggested by magicandre1981 in a related [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1020629/what-is-the-cause-of-a-high-cpu-usage-of-system-and-compressed-memory-in-windo), I downloaded the Windows 10 SDK and used the WPR to create a [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzPj6QSixlpBSUNWQVdjWUdRcFE) which I tried to analyze using WPA. I read a bit about it but I end up with unknown processes. As my experience is very new and superficial I was wondering whether it is indeed possible to find the name of the process. This is my only computer and I need it to work so I am desperate to try anything.

More details:
I looked Computation>CPU Usage (Precise) and then proceeded to find the thread and process with the highest %CPU usage but there is no process name.

I provided the file so you can see for yourselves.

EDIT:

1) I created a new trace and the CPU sampling data is also missing after the start.

2) I have noticed that the "system and compressed memory" process is oscillating very regularly.

3) No high CPU usage of this process happens when I am in Safe Mode.

Another .etl [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzPj6QSixlpBQkxEOTVTZHYwMXc/view?usp=sharing) using the command line this time.

Comment: You haven't really quantified what is 'slow.'  Judging from the stock specs of this machine, I'm not surprised at this (AMD cpu w/ slow clock rate and small cache, 5400 rpm drive, 4 gb ram); this is more like a tablet then a real laptop.  Sorry that this doesn't answer your real question.

Comment: capture a new trace. The CPU sampling data are missing for a unknown reason for most of the time. I only see some at the start of the trace.

Comment: I created a new trace and the CPU sampling data is missing again. Did I forget a step to do before the recording?

Comment: don't use WPRUI from WPT, run the commandline version which is part of Windows 10: **"C:\Windows\system32\wpr.exe" -start  CPU && timeout 30 && "C:\Windows\system32\wpr.exe" -stop C:\Result.etl**. Now look if it includes the CPU sampling data

Comment: It includes it but it stops too. File in the edits. We can see that the guilty process oscillates a lot and that the thread ID is 532 (can you confirm please?). But I still have no idea what to do.

Comment: I don't have the permission to download it

Comment: I am very sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: I got the file via the email request

Answer (score 2):

[Analyzing the ETL with WPA](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis) shows that the cpu usage comes from the AMD/ATI GPU driver `atikmdag.sys`:

[image]

Your driver version is "`8.01.01.1533`", This looks like the older Catalyst 15.8. Try the [latest driver from AMD](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/apu?os=Windows%2010%20-%2064).

Comment: I did that and now I have a black screen after boot. I did a system restore and it solved the black screen. I tried installing only what I needed, unchecking several unrelated drivers but it did not work. Now my plan is to actually try an earlier version of catalyst. What do you think?

Comment: yes, try other AMD drivers until you found a driver that works and no longer shows the atikmdag.sys usage

Comment: have you found a working driver?

Comment: I tried 5 different drivers. Black screen or high CPU usage every single time. I will try more as soon as I have time. I have had to create a partition and dual-boot to be able to work on my computer.

Comment: ask this AMD in their forums if they have plans to fix this issue